# Correct way to get data from database that only the customer owns in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am writing my first application in Spring Boot so sorry if this is a stupid question.
I have a "customer" table in database and a "building" table which has customer_id as a foreign key so I know which customers own which buildings.
As I understand it right now, in repository folder should be BuildingRepository.java which handles communicating to the database building table. I have "getAll()" method written in there but it returns the list of all buildings regardless of customer_id. Then I have BuildingServiceImpl.java which is the "layer" below the REST API endpoints which also has getAll() method to return all buildings. Should I specify the customer_id as a parameter in the repository or should I specify it in the serviceImpl to keep the repository strictly for basic database interaction in order to return only buildings that customer owns?

Here is a method getAll() in BuildingRepository.java

```
public List<Building> getAll() {
    final String sql = "select * from building";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, buildingRowMapper);
}
```

and here is a method getAll() in BuildingServiceImpl.java

```
public List<Building> getAll() {
    return buildingRepository.getAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these query **"select * from building b left join customer c on b.customer_id=c.customer_id"** or **"select * from building,customer c where b.customer_id=c.customer_id"**.

if you need to return specific columns you can always use the return type as **List<Object[]>** and in-service layer you need to typecast them back into the respective data type. Let me know if you required that query and I will provide you the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I know how to write queries. Let me ask the question more clearly. I want to filter out only the buildings with the correct customer_id. Should I do it in repository or in the service layer ?

Comment: The selective data is always faster and more efficient than the aggregate data, but sometimes we require different sets of same data in different processes, in that case java filtering(in service layer) is more effective.